# Error raised with node

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I have the following code that raises "undefined control sequence" error on the line that draws redarrow. When I continue with compilation, it does produce the red arrow, but gives this error that I can't figure out.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}        

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,arrows}
\tikzstyle{redarrow}=[->, >=triangle 90,dashed, red]

\tikzstyle{every entity} = []
\tikzstyle{smentity} = [rectangle, draw, black, 
                      minimum width=4em, minimum height=2em,
                      every entity]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, every edge/.style={link}]


\node[smentity] (d1) {1111 1101};

\draw[redarrow] (d1.130) -- ++(0,0.4) node[above]{\alert{11101}} -|  (d1.35);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It has a beamer related command `\alert`. You can use `\textcolor{red}{11101}` instead

Comment: Thank you... I am not having a good day making naive mistakes. I copied the code from a beamer presentation and never caught on to the \alert. Much appreciated.

Comment: @percusse sounds like you've fixed this; could you post an answer- otherwise, if the problem is solved, should this question be closed as too localized?

Comment: @cmhughes Better close it too localized. I've voted for that